# R kable/kable - multiple dataframes in one call function

Tags: r, knitr, kable

I have long script with 15+ dataframes, right now my script generates html file for each dataframe. I'd like to create only one html file with one kable function. Please note that I have to keep this code in my R script, I can't create new markdown document.

Here is how I create html file

```
kable(my_dataframe1, "html") %>%
  kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c("striped", "hover")) %>%
  cat(., file = "result.html")
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you would not use an R markdown file to do this... It would be so much easier.

Anyway, a way to work around this is:

```
dataframe_list <- list(
    my_dataframe1,
    my_dataframe2,
    my_dataframe3
    # and so on
)

kable(dataframe_list, "html") %>%
  kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c("striped", "hover")) %>%
  cat(., file = "result.html")
```